# Typo3 - Folder "/" does not exist - Error

Tags: server, apache2, error-handling

when I am in the backend in the filelist Module or want to link something, I get the error message: "**#1314516810: Folder "/" does not exist.**" (see screenshot). The folder exists of course, and everything worked until recently, the error suddenly appeared from one day to the next. I checked the fileadmin settings too and everything seems fine (see screenshot). I have already googled the error and searched several forums, but I cannot find a solution to my problem.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and how I can fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

- Typo3-Version 8.7.32
- Webserver: Apache
- PHP-Version: 7.4.28
- Database: MariaDB 10.3.34
- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- Server Management via Plesk Obsidian 18.0.43

Regards

Error message:

[image: error message]

Fileadmin settings:

[image: fileadmin settings]

Answer (score 0):

Use ./
Instead of /
It's gonna fix your prob

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Do you mean I have to change the base path to "fileadmin./" ?